# Most Efficient Way to Do Multiple SQL Queries (Subqueries vs CTE with JOINS)

Tags: sql, subquery, common-table-expression

This is more an abstract question of general SQL practice than an actual implementation as I believe I know how to right each version.

So I have one entity type, call it entity A, that I can retrieve via a standard query, something like so (this is a contrived example so apologies for syntax):

```
# Query A
SELECT DISTINCT tableName.A
FROM super_duper_long_table_name AS tableName
WHERE tableName.X = "something" and tableName.A IS NOT NULL
```

But I don't really care about entity A. I only need it to get to other entities that I can easily look up based on A. I can look up each of these important entities with subqueries like so:

```
# Query B
SELECT tableName2.B1, tableName2.B2, tableName2.B3
FROM super_duper_long_table_name2 AS tableName2
WHERE tableName2.A IN
(
# Query A, same as above
)
GROUP BY tableName2.B1, tableName2.B2, tableName2.B3
```

So my question is, is it better to do several versions of query B (likely 3) to get the important entities using the identical subquery many times (where if I ever change it, I'll have to update multiple places) or is it better to do a CTE with JOINS for each important entity that I want and form it into one monster query?

Or even, is it better to intentionally separate them, so call query A, save the results in a temporary var, then feed the enumerated entities into the WHERE clause of each version of query B?

Sorry if this is too vague and starts too much of a discussion, but I'm not super familiar with best practices for SQL so this seemed like as good a place as any to start. Thanks!

Comment: What's your DBMS?  Generally, `IN()` won't be your best option, but each DBMS handles `IN()`, `EXISTS()` and `JOIN` a bit differently, which are basically your 3 options here.  Some optimize all of them into the same query, while others there is a definitive best option.  That said, repeating anything across queries that will require another table scan is a bad idea.  For your example, you should put A into a CTE or temp table then join to other tables from it in your later queries.  Place indexes on the join predicate fields for optimal results.

Comment: You can turn on "Include Actual Execution Plan" and determine which is the most efficient.  It breaks down the steps SQL server went through to run your query and the cost.

Comment: I would recommend to use temp tables to store your subquery results. It's much better to manipulate and control rather than joining multiple tables.  I work in the data warehouse department and temp tables are crucial to our success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a CTE (or temp table) for queryA, then `JOIN` from/to it in all later queries:

```
; WITH QueryA AS (
SELECT DISTINCT tableName.A
FROM super_duper_long_table_name AS tableName
WHERE tableName.X = "something" and tableName.A IS NOT NULL)

SELECT tableName2.B1, tableName2.B2, tableName2.B3
FROM QueryA AS A
JOIN super_duper_long_table_name2 AS tableName2 ON tableName2.A = QueryA.A
```

This way, you will only do the filtering logic on query A a single time.  If you subquery it in each version of query B, you'll waste a bunch of time reprocessing query A when you don't need to.

Answer (score 1):

Remember that group by is for aggregation function and not a sort of fake distinct clase  .. anyway  suuld be better 
an inner join instead of a IN clause

the use of select table in JOIN with main select is tipical  in SQL  .. (or CTE) essentially the result is the are the intesction of common elements

```
  SELECT tableName2.B1, tableName2.B2, tableName2.B3
  FROM super_duper_long_table_name2 AS tableName2
  INNER JOIN (
      SELECT DISTINCT tableName.A as TA
      FROM super_duper_long_table_name AS tableName
      WHERE tableName.X = "something" and tableName.A IS NOT NULL
  ) T ON tableName2.A  = T.TA
```

*The use of group by without aggregation function is deprecated  in sql and in most db version is not  allowed*